# Mail sent with SMTP and Accesstoken using scopes

Tags: c#, email, gmail, scopes

I want to mail sent using SMTP client using access token

**While using single scopes it's working**

https://mail.google.com/

**While i'm using other scopes SMTP client not connected**
need to full permission to connect smtp?

Comment: You need to use Credentials instead of a username/password.  Google mail want a secure connection so a Credential has to be used.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.credentials?view=netframework-4.8  You need to replace the default credential with a username/password in the credential.

Comment: I don't want to sent mail with api, I don't want to sent mail with smtp using username and password.       I need **smtp** using **accesstoken**

Comment: I not talking about API.  Read the google email website for the correct parameters to use to c# SMTP.